# React Material-UI Treeview the prp type 'nodeID' is marked as required

Tags: json, reactjs, rest, material-ui, prop

I'm experiencing the following issue.

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `nodeId` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(TreeItem)`, but its value is `undefined`.
in ForwardRef(TreeItem) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TreeItem)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TreeItem)) (at Treeview.js:77)
in ul (created by ForwardRef(TreeView))
in ForwardRef(TreeView) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TreeView)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TreeView)) (at Treeview.js:84)
in CustomizedTreeView (at Inbox.js:97)
in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (at Inbox.js:93)
in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at Inbox.js:92)
in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at Inbox.js:91)
in div (at Inbox.js:90)
in Inbox (created by WithStyles(Inbox))
in WithStyles(Inbox) (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (at App.js:18)
in Switch (at App.js:14)
in main (at App.js:13)
in App (at src/index.js:26)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:24)
```

my code in the rendering Class looks like the following:

```
class Inbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Folder: [],
      loading: true,
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.loading = false;
    getFolder().then((result) => this.setState({ Folder: result }));
    this.setState({ folderstate: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { Folder, folderstate } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="Inbox">
        <Grid wrap="wrap" container>
          <Grid item xs={3}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
              <Typography>Ordner Struktur:</Typography>
              <Divider />

              {folderstate ? <Tree data={Folder} /> : <h1> Loading </h1>}

              <Divider />
              <Button>Aktualisieren</Button>
            </Paper>
            <Grid item xs={5}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}></Paper>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

so I fetch an object which looks like this:

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 11,
                        "children": [],
                        "name": "OCryezdlGf"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "QlcmTxEIBf"
            }
        ],
        "name": "KBMTGYDsNp"
    },
```

and try to parse this in the Treeview:

```
export default function CustomizedTreeView(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const renderTree = (nodes) => (
    <TreeItem key={nodes.id} nodeId={nodes.id} label={nodes.name}>
      {Array.isArray(nodes.children)
        ? nodes.children.map((node) => renderTree(node))
        : null}
    </TreeItem>
  );
  return (
    <TreeView
      className={classes.root}
      defaultExpanded={["1"]}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<MinusSquare />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<PlusSquare />}
      defaultEndIcon={<CloseSquare />}
    >
      {renderTree(props.data)}
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```

so if I manually pass an the Test Object from the Material-UI Site:

```
const data = {
  id: "1",
  name: "Parent",
  children: [
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Child - 1",
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Child - 3",
      children: [
        {
          id: "4",
          name: "Child - 4",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

the Treeview renders as excepted. Unfortunately not with the data I get from the Rest API, as i'm fairly new to Javascript hoppefully some of you awesome guys can help me out :)

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The warning is due to undefined property.
Initialize the prop 'nodeId' with a string.

```
const renderTree = (nodes) => (
<TreeItem 
  key={nodes.id}
  nodeId={nodes.id ? nodes.id : "defaultNodeId"}
  label={nodes.name}>

  {Array.isArray(nodes.children)
    ? nodes.children.map((node) => renderTree(node))
    : null}
</TreeItem>);
```